# Not able to link a program in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

Whenever  I try to execute  a program in VC++  it says build errors and that the .exe file is not available.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: uahd, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\uahd\Debug\uahd.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you mean to create a console app?

Comment: No, windows application

Comment: Did you provide a WinMain function, as all windows applications require?

Comment: yeah I did. it says the .exe is not available where its specified

Comment: The `.exe` was not created beacause of the fatal `unresolved external` link error, so that's the problem you need to figure out. It would help if you posted your `WinMain` code, plus the compile and link commands from the build logfiles.

Comment: It's fixed now. All I had to do was run it with administrative privilege .-. Sorry for wasting your time :v